# JS function issue, I've been trying to solve this for like an hour now even though its a simple issue, I want to display the hex value of the #input1

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to take the value coal and then display it outside of this function in another function but can't figure out how to do it. I know this code might not be the most efficient but I've only been coding a couple of weeks so any tips would be great thanks, I know the names of the variables are bad but I plan on improving it soon.

```js
let valueCol = "";
const i2n = document.getElementById("input1");
i2n.onchange = function valGet() {
  valueCol = i2n.value;
  colorBase.style.background = valueCol;
  document.getElementById("head").innerHTML = valueCol;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#color-base {
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vw;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  background-color: blue;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sweetContainer {
  grid-area: sweet;
  background-color: green;
  height: 90vh;
}

.stats {
  grid-area: stat;
  background-color: red;
  height: 90vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: head;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10vh;
}

.colSel {
  height: 5vh;
  width: 8vw;
}

.container {
  grid-template-areas: 'head head head' 'stat sweet sweet' 'stat sweet sweet';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sweetContainer">
    <input type="color" name="" class="colSel" id="input1" value="Enter name">
    <div id="color-base" class="sweet">
      <div id="flavor" class="added"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
    <h1 id="objectDisplay">stats for the object</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="head">Name of company</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please, try improving the title of your question by only including the relevant parts

Comment: `colorBase` is not defined here

Comment: I think you're only missing `const colorBase = document.getElementById("color-base");` (as @Alex noticed)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing this line

```
const colorBase = document.getElementById("color-base");
```

before assigning background style.

Check the same example here with correction https://codepen.io/shreyasikhar/pen/QWmVdJb